# Python program working in shell but not when run from IDLE

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a script, and then it went wrong, but in the python shell, I typed the same code in the script and it worked. What happened? Here's my code:

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-
import pymysql
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'Hjd4132！', 'pytest')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from demo')
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print(data[3])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

**Here's my error message:**

```
(1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.close()
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

Comment: So your line `cursor = ..` wasn't executed. Exception appeared in `connect()` method.

Comment: I changed MySQL 5.7 to 5.1, and the problem was solved without modifying the code. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

that's the kind of error you get when the user or password are wrong, maybe you should check the line where you start the connection, it's the reason why cursor is not defined.

Comment: i can use the password enter mysql ,and in the python shell it worked,but when i ran this script,it made a mistake

Comment: I changed MySQL 5.7 to 5.1, and the problem was solved without modifying the code. Thank you for your reply!